# JavaScript AddEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

So I'm trying to make a slideshow where the user can click next to browse through pictures. I've created an array for the images:

```
var staff = new Array();
staff[0] = "/images/Isabelle.png";
staff[1] = "/images/Nook.png";
staff[2] = "/images/Timothy_Tommy.png";
staff[3] = "/images/Mabel.png";
staff[4] = "/images/Sable.png";
staff[5] = "/images/Labelle.png";
```

And a function for changing the images:

```
var i = 1;
function nextImage(){
    document.getElementById("slide").src = staff[i];
    if(i < staff.length)
        i++;
    else i = 0; //wraps around to first image
}
```

The addEventListener function call I added into a registerHandlers function that I initialize with onload:

```
document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click",nextImage,false);
```

And the image and "next" button are placed in divs inside body:

```
<div class="container">
    <img id ="slide" src="images/Isabelle.png" />
</div>
<div id="next">
    <button type="button">Next</button>
</div>
```

I've tried looking up solutions and example code but I can't seem to make this work

Comment: `document.body` doesn't have a method `getElementById`

Comment: `document.getElementById("next")`

Comment: Did you look to see if there are errors in the console?

Comment: the path to the img in the html is relative, the ones in the script are absolute. this might be an issue.

Comment: I changed it do document.get but it still doesn't work.

Comment: where is your script-tag? head? body? before or after the corresponding html-nodes? and you still owe us an answer wether you get any errors.

Comment: For less code, consider `document.getElementById("slide").src = staff[++i % staff.length];`

Comment: @thomas— "*… that I initialize with onload.*". To the OP, why attach the listener to the div and not the button?

Comment: @RobG thanks, didn't get that in the right context; but still, @ muditae sure that the code is executed?* and you don't get any error-messages? *depending on how you included your script and implemented this onload-handler you might add it after the event was fired; It's hard to debug sth. that seems to simply don't work, although everything seems right; **seems**

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the event handler as DHTML, so you don't have to wait for it to load the elements, just in case that's an issue:

`<button type="button" onclick="nextImage();">Next</button>`

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it is considered bad practice to combine your events and your presentation layer in this way